# How to set the font size of text in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

How can I make the size of the font in a label larger?

I used this function to display the text :

```
function OnGUI()
{
    GUI.color = Color.green;
    GUI.Label(Rect(500,350,200,50),"Lose");
}
```

And that results in:

> [image]

How can I make this text bigger?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Unity's GUI supports "rich text" tags now.

http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/StyledText.html

So this would work:

```
GUI.Label(Rect(500,350,200,50),"<color=green><size=40>Lose</size></color>");
```

Comment: Ha, that shows me for not using Unity's GUI stuff for anything other than editor extensions. :) Thanks for that. +1

Comment: @Bart Yeah, it's handy, but I still wouldn't use the immediate mode GUI for anything besides editor extensions and an FPS counter.

Answer (score 18):

Simply create an appropriate [`GUIStyle`](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/class-GUIStyle.html) and set the `fontSize`. Pass this to your label and you're good to go.

So something like this:

```c#
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class FontSizeExample : MonoBehaviour 
{

    GUIStyle smallFont;
    GUIStyle largeFont;

    void Start () 
    {
        smallFont = new GUIStyle();
        largeFont = new GUIStyle();

        smallFont.fontSize = 10;
        largeFont.fontSize = 32;
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        GUI.Label(new Rect(100, 100, 300, 50), "SMALL HELLO WORLD", smallFont);
        GUI.Label(new Rect(100, 200, 300, 50), "LARGE HELLO WORLD", largeFont);
    }
}
```

will result in

[image]