# JavaScript -- Unity Changing Button Font Size via Script

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine

I have been working on a game recently and It's going very good. Today I started working on the menu and I created a button, but there is one problem, I have no idea how to change the size of the font :/

Here is the script:

[image: The Code]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change text of Unity 4.6 UI button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27510743/change-text-of-unity-4-6-ui-button)

Comment: This is a duplicate to close, just FYI  you can NOT use the extremely old "ongui" system, Unity are removing it and it is no longer supported. Good news the ordinary Unity.UI system is incredibly easier to use https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/the-new-ui  Here is a full tutorial (1) click add canvas (2) click add button. You're done

Answer (score 0):

Pass a GUIStyle into the function and set the font size inside the GUIStyle.

Somthing like this should really work.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class FontSizeExample : MonoBehaviour 
{

    GUIStyle smallFont;
    GUIStyle largeFont;

    void Start () 
    {
        smallFont = new GUIStyle();
        largeFont = new GUIStyle();

        smallFont.fontSize = 10;
        largeFont.fontSize = 32;
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        GUI.Label(new Rect(100, 100, 300, 50), "SMALL HELLO WORLD", smallFont);
        GUI.Label(new Rect(100, 200, 300, 50), "LARGE HELLO WORLD", largeFont);
    }
}
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19135791/how-to-set-the-font-size-of-text-in-unity)

Comment: I get an error saying: "Unexpected Token: GUIStyle"

Comment: Maybe you need to do some imports?

Comment: hi @phenxd although this is a well-written answer, pls do not answer many-times duplicates.  There is a huge problem on SO of Unity3D clutter of ***very easy questions, which already have full answers***. I suggest it's best just to click Dupe.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I researched the GUIStyle a bit and I did this:

var guiStyle : guiStyle;

and then I did

if(GUI.Button(Rect(playX, playY, sizePlayX, sizePlayY), "Play", guiStyle)) { code }

And I got a new thing in the inspector of the script where I could change everything, the font size, color only problem was that the border disappeard... Anyone know how to fix this ?

Comment: If you're still facing problems, you'd be best served to write a new question for this - most people don't look through the answers to see if there are still lingering questions.